# while using Regex removing all space from the string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string Like this:

```
dim ItemDesc as string=PHOTO COPY PAPER A4 GALAXY
```

if string contains any special character then i want to remove that,so i give code like this:

```
 ItemDesc = Regex.Replace(ItemDesc, "[^A-Za-z0-9\-/]", "")
```

so this time i am getting  itemdes value without space

```
PHOTOCOPYPAPERA4GALAXY
```

i want to keep my space like that only ..so how i can re-write the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just should add space (or space characters) to your regex:

ie:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\-\/\ ]
```

https://regex101.com/r/dH4bC7/2

Comment: `\s` is not space, it is all whitespace including newlines.

Comment: so my final command is like this :  ItemDesc = Regex.Replace(ItemDesc, "[^A-Za-z0-9\-\/\ ]", "") ..this is correct?

Comment: The best way to kwnow is testing, but in theory, that regex means, all the characters that are not (^) some of this A..Z,a..z,0-9, or "-", "\", " ", will be replaced  by "" !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
[^A-Za-z0-9/\p{Zs}-]
```

In C# regex, you do not need to escape `/` and to match all spaces you can use a `\p{Zs}` Unicode category class.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5EA-Za-z0-9%2F%5Cp%7BZs%7D-%5D&i=PHOTO%20COPY%20PAPER%20A4%C2%A7GALAXY&r=)

The regex `[^A-Za-z0-9/\p{Zs}-]` matches any character that is NOT:

- A Latin uppercase letter (`A-Z`)
- A Latin lowercase letter (`a-z`)
- A digit (`0-9`)
- A forward slash (`/`)
- Any Unicode space (`\p{Zs}`)
- A hyphen (`-`).

Comment: I always forget about Unicode Separator... Thanks for reminding me